# Visual basic, fill a combobox

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008

This code gives me system.data.datarowview show in combobox.But I want to fill the combo box with data. whats the error?

```
Dim adclasstecher As New SqlDataAdapter
Dim tbclassteacher As New DataTable
If cnSchool.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then cnSchool.Open()
cmclassteacher.Connection = cnSchool
cmclassteacher.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Teachers"
cmclassteacher.ExecuteNonQuery()

adclasstecher.SelectCommand = cmclassteacher
adclasstecher.Fill(tbclassteacher)

With cmbclzteachr
    .DataSource = tbclassteacher
    .DisplayMember = "ClassTeacher"
    .SelectedIndex = 0
End With
cnSchool.Close()
```

Comment: here don't need excutenonquery and what error show ?

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim adclasstecher As New SqlDataAdapter
Dim tbclassteacher As New DataTable
If cnSchool.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then cnSchool.Open()
cmclassteacher.Connection = cnSchool
cmclassteacher.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Teachers"
cmclassteacher.ExecuteNonQuery()

adclasstecher.SelectCommand = cmclassteacher
adclasstecher.Fill(tbclassteacher)

With cmbclzteachr
    .DataSource = tbclassteacher
    .DisplayMember = "ClassTeacher"
    .SelectedIndex = 0
    .databind() //you need to bind the data after providing datasource
End With

cnSchool.Close()
```